# How to structure router.js file in VueJs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I want to structure my router.js file as currently there is around 500 lines of code in it.

```
{
            path: "/",
            component: () => import("./../src/views/dashboard/Dashboard.vue"),
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                title: "Dashboard"
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/regionWiseDashboard",
            component: () => import("./../src/views/dashboard/RegionWiseDashboard.vue"),
            meta: {
                auth: true,
                title: "Dashboard"
            }
        },
```

The above code is repeating for every component I include in my project which just makes the code look more and more unreadable. Can I structure it anyhow? Maybe put all files in an JSON or divide the main js file into children js files?

Comment: `an JSON object` - no such thing ... did you mean JSON **or** an object?

Comment: @JaromandaX that was a typing error. Sorry for that. Your comment would have been of more help if you would have answered my question though.

Comment: your question is, "maybe put all the files in a JSON" - this makes no sense, how does one put files into JSON? so I can't answer that. "or divide the main js file into children js files" - this again makes no sense since your problem is with a single object you are passing to create the router

Answer (score 3):

How I structured my routes in vue.

**First**: create a folder named routes, inside this folder, create subfolders depends on how you group your routes. Example, villages, dashboard, user

**Second**:  create a main route inside your routes folder. This main route will hold and import all your routes made in villages, dashboard, user.

**last**: import this main route to your main app.js